# Why native ads shrink when created manually

Tags: android, mopub

native ads shrink when created manually. that is the code and layout I'm using for rendering native ads:

```
private NativeAdService(Context context) {
        moPubNative = new MoPubNative(context.getApplicationContext(), "XXX", new MoPubNative.MoPubNativeNetworkListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNativeLoad(NativeAd nativeAd) {
                NativeAdService.this.nativeAd = nativeAd;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNativeFail(NativeErrorCode errorCode) {
            }
        });

        ViewBinder viewBinder = new ViewBinder.Builder(R.layout.native_ad_layout)
                .iconImageId(R.id.native_ad_icon_image)
                .titleId(R.id.native_ad_title)
                .textId(R.id.native_ad_text)
                .build();

        MoPubStaticNativeAdRenderer moPubStaticNativeAdRenderer = new MoPubStaticNativeAdRenderer(viewBinder);
        moPubNative.registerAdRenderer(moPubStaticNativeAdRenderer);

        moPubNative.makeRequest();

    }
```

thats how I render the ad:

```
  View view = nativeAd.createAdView(context, null);
        nativeAd.renderAdView(view);
        return view;
```

the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBlueText">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorBlackText">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/native_ad_icon_image"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/native_ad_title"
                android:layout_width="2dp"
                android:layout_height="29dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="Title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/native_ad_text"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="49dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:text="AdText" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is what I get: somehow match_parent value doesn't work at all.

[image]